# Which point on or inside or outside the frame move in a circular trajectory?

Tags: geometry, transformation

[image]

Which point on or inside or outside the frame move in a circular trajectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what happens when a corner hits the circle.  The rectangle immediately begins moving in a straight line ... until the next corner hits the circle.  No straight lines in a circle, there is no purely circular motion for the rectangle or any point in it.